# Adding a list of images in jscrollpane and show it

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlabel, jlist

I need to add some images in jscrollpane and show the correct image when my jlist string is selected with relative image... but i have some doubt to do it.

```
    public class Tela{
    private JList<String> list;

    public Tela(){

        JFrame display = new JFrame();
        display.setTitle("Maquina de Refrigerante");
        String labels[] = { "Coca-Cola", "Fanta Laranja", "Fanta-Uva", 
                 "Sprite"};
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));


        JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        JPanel secondPanel = new JPanel();
        //downPanel.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        //downPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 30, 260));
        secondPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        secondPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110,110));

        final JButton comprar = new JButton("Comprar");
        comprar.setEnabled(false); 


        list = new JList<String>(labels);
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        list.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 3, 3, 3));
        list.setSelectedIndex(0);
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane();
        pane.getViewport().add(list);
        firstPanel.add(pane);

        list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                int selections[] = list.getSelectedIndices();
                //String selectedValue = list.getSelectedValue();
                Object selectionValues[] = list.getSelectedValues();
                for (int i = 0, n = selections.length; i < n; i++) {
                    if (i == 0) {
               System.out.println("Value" + selectionValues[i] );
                    }}
               comprar.setEnabled(true);

            }
        });


        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("assets/fantalogo.jpg");
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(new JLabel(image));
        panel.add(jsp);

        buttonPanel.add(comprar);
        buttonPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,4)));
        buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

        panel.add(firstPanel);
        panel.add(secondPanel);
        panel.add(buttonPanel);
        //panel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        display.add(panel);
        display.setSize(550, 500);
        display.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        display.setDefaultCloseOperation(display.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        display.setVisible(true);

        comprar.addActionListener(new Paga());
    }


}
```

in my code how i can implemments it and view the correctly output?

Comment: Just as suggestion: Why don't use a `ListCellRenderer` to add pictures and descriptions in the `JList` itself instead using a separate `JScrollPane` to hold pictures?

Comment: @dic19 I need to select a item in my list of names(labels) and relative this render correct image how may i use ListCellRenderer?

Comment: @Wesley, have you read the tutorial yet???

Comment: @camickr yeah, but i don't know how to use it. `JPanel secondPanel = new JPanel();
     ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("assets/fantalogo.jpg");
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(new JLabel(image));
        secondPanel.add(jsp);` in this case where i can use a List of images when i select a item my image change conform my item?

Comment: What do you mean you don't know how to use it? The tutorial does what you want. Start with a working example and then modify it for your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html). You find an example that does almost exactly what you want. The example uses a combo box, but the code for a JList will be very similar. That is the combo box contains a list of Strings and when you select an item the matching image is displayed.